# myPHP If statement always firing as true with int number

Tags: php

```
$q = "SELECT currentlevel FROM users WHERE users={$_SESSION[user_id]}" ;
$r = mysqli_query( $link, $q ) ;
if ($r == 0)
{
    header("Location: EXAMPLE-WEBSITE.co.uk");
}
else{
```

I'm trying to query my database to obtain a result that will be a 1 or a 0. The user is currently logged in, if the result returns as 0, i want the user to be redirected to another page, but if the result returned is 1 then i want the rest of the code to execute.

For some reason, my result being received appears to constantly be 0.

Any advice is majorly appreciated.

Comment: $r is the success (or not) of the query, not the returned value from it

Comment: So what would i need to do to create a variable to store the value returned from the database, then use that in the if statement to compare if its 1 or 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to fetch the value from the row and then compare it:

```
$currentLevel = 1;
$res = $link->query($query) or die($link->error);

if ($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
    $currentLevel = $row->currentlevel;
}

if ($currentLevel == 0) {
    // It's 0
} else {
    // Non-zero or no record found
}
```

Comment: ....but mixing and matching object oriented and procedural interfaces is not good practice.

Comment: oh i dont know with a rep like yours it would be nice to see you answering with 'best' practice in mind.

Comment: Thanks for this jspcal, but i think i may be understanding (sorry im new to this). I'm trying that code but i'm still getting the same issue? Is there anything additional i need to do ontop of your code?

Comment: Try `var_dump($row)` to verify the record

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do this would be to create the condition in your SQL statement by adding `AND currentlevel = 0`, then you can just check if the query returns true:

```
$q = "SELECT currentlevel FROM users WHERE users = {$_SESSION[user_id]} AND currentlevel = 0";
if ( mysqli_query( $link, $q ) ) { //rows returned, currentlevel = 0
    header("Location: EXAMPLE-WEBSITE.co.uk");
}
else { //no rows returned
```